# ember.js - is returning a new arrayproxy each time bad practice

Tags: ember.js

I would like to know if this is extremely bad practice or not.

I am overriding arrangedContent and filtering the content when a user selects an item from a dropdown or types some text into an input so this function could run quite a lot:

I want to sort the results after I have filtered the results.  I was thinking of doing this but thought against it:

```
arrangedContent: ( ->
  filtered = @get('content').filter (item) ->
    #filter content

  Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins Ember.SortableMixin,
    sortProperties: ['name']
).property('model.[]', 'searchText')
```

I am curious to know what are the implications in terms of performance and potential memory leaks of doing something like this that could be ran every time a keystroke happens.

I used a normal sort on the content, but I am curious to know if this is really bad or not.

Comment: Honestly I think that having a `create` statement in a computed property is bad, because as you already said it would use a lot o unnecessary memory for new instances of the ArrayProxy. You should think of a possible arrayproxy that you `reuse` instead of creating new ones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad practice that has caused me hours of pain on more occasions than I care to recall.

It is usually better to modify an array that is being observed instead of replacing it.